Running a JavaScript console.log command doesn't output anything in Visual Studio Code

Whenever I try to run a code, for example:
console.log("Hello");
Instead of finishing with the outcome "Hello" it just ends the script without display anything anywhere.

You're running a JS script in an IDE that has a terminal, not a web browser that has a console, so that may be the reason for it not appearing to do anything.

TylerH Other people do it to like this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqXzpj2jfOU

Did you save the file before running?

How exactly are you running the file?
